# what is the -n operator in bash shell script and stand for?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I found this `-n` operator in bash shell script. I don't have any clue about **this and searched**, but didn't find any helpful resource.

*This is the script code:*

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ -n "$1" ] ....
```

***I also tried to get the output of the `-n` like:***

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n  #return nothing
```

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: `man sh`, or `man test` or `man echo`

Comment: `man [` tells you: _the length of STRING is nonzero_ and `man echo`: _do not output the trailing newline_.

Comment: Take a look: `help test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-n string` returns true if the length of the string is non-zero.

This is documented in [Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)